# Gitweb - name of last person to commit

Tags: perl, git, cgi, gitweb

I'm looking to add the name of the person who made the last commit to each project on the GitWeb project list, so instead of

```
14 min ago
```

it says something like

```
14 min ago (Someone's Name)
```

I've had a look through `gitweb.cgi` and found the point where the string is written (line 5488 in mine), but I don't really know how to proceed.

Has anyone already done this? Or can anyone offer a quick solution?

Comment: You know, it could be line 8854 as well; still gives nothing to solve the problem. Why don't you write this line (or this block) here instead? )

Comment: Agree with @raina77ow. Once you've found some sort of version, (there's a `our $version =""` line in the code) it's easier to help. I've found a version `1.7.0.2` with a quick google and came up with the `sub git_get_last_activity` which is in line 2542. That gets the age and can be modified to also get the name. See the `git for-each-ref` manpage. I cannot test this, though, so I cannot propose a proper answer.

Comment: The version we're using is `1.7.10.msysgit.1`. I've found `git_get_last_activity` in there, so I'll see what I can do with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to simbabque for pointing me to `git_get_last_activity`. My solution (possibly sub-optimal, let me know if it is):

Change `git_get_last_activity` to

```
sub git_get_last_activity {
my ($path) = @_;
my $fd;

$git_dir = "$projectroot/$path";
open($fd, "-|", git_cmd(), 'for-each-ref',
     '--format=%(committer)',
     '--sort=-committerdate',
     '--count=1',
     'refs/heads') or return;
my $most_recent = <$fd>;
close $fd or return;
if (defined $most_recent &&
    $most_recent =~ / (\d+) [-+][01]\d\d\d$/) {
  my $bracket_position = rindex($most_recent, "<");
  my $committer_name = substr($most_recent, 0, $bracket_position - 1);
    my $timestamp = $1;
    my $age = time - $timestamp;
    return ($age, age_string($age), $committer_name);
}
return (undef, undef, undef);
}
```

Then search for where that is called later (should only be once) and change

```
($pr->{'age'}, $pr->{'age_string'}) = @activity;
```

to be

```
($pr->{'age'}, $pr->{'age_string'}, $pr->{'committer'}) = @activity;
```

Then go to `git_project_list_rows` and change

```
(defined $pr->{'age_string'} ? $pr->{'age_string'} : "No commits") . "</td>\n" .
```

to

```
(defined $pr->{'age_string'} ? $pr->{'age_string'} . ' (' . $pr->{'committer'} . ')' : "No commits") . "</td>\n" .
```